# A sample regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have sample content string repeated in a file which I wanna to retrieve its double value from it.the string content is "(AIC)|234.654 |" which I wanna retrieve the 234.654 from that...the "(AIC)|" is always fixed but the numbers change in other occasions so I am using regular expression as follow..but it says there is no match using below expression..any help would be appreciated

```
String contents="(AIC)|234.654 |";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("AIC\\u0029{1}\\u007C{1}\\d+u002E{1}\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(contents);
boolean b = m.find();
String t=m.group();
```

The above expression doest find any match and throw exception..
Thanks for any help

Comment: Pay attention here: `+u002E{1}`. And `String content=` vs. `p.matcher(contents);`.

Comment: Why not simply `\(AIC\)\|([^|]+)`?

Comment: Why not simply `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several typos, but beside them, you say you need to match the number inside the brackets, but you are referring to the whole match with `.group()`. You need to set a capturing group to access that number with `.group(1)`.

Here is a fixed code:

```
String content="(AIC)|234.654 |";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("AIC\\)\\|(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wUSBmo)

If the number can be integer, just use an optional non-capturing group around the decimal part: `Pattern.compile("AIC\\)\\|(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");`

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex should do the work:

```
(?<=\|)[\d\.]*(?=\s*\|)
```

It will only match digits and dots after a `|` and before an optional space and another `|`

And the complete code:

```
String content="(AIC)|234.654 |";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\|)[\\d\\.]*(?=\\s*\\|)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
boolean b = m.find();
String t=m.group();
```